# unable to perform request - response

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-simulator

I wrote the following code for client - server communication in Blackberry but its not working.

I am sending data via POST.

I am not receiving any response from the server while testing using Blackberry simulator.

With Android & iPhone , I am able to get the response from the same server url & with the same request parameters.

```
private void communicate() {

         HttpConnection hc = null; 
         DataInputStream dis = null;
         DataOutputStream dos = null;
         StringBuffer messagebuffer = new StringBuffer();
         try{
         String input="firstname="+ fName.getText().trim()+
         "&lastname=" + lName.getText().trim()+"&platform=blackberry";
         String url = "http://127.0.0.1:80/index/login";

         hc = (HttpConnection)
         Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE); // Set the request method
         hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
         hc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "BlackBerry");
         hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         hc.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
         Integer.toString(input.length()));

         dos = hc.openDataOutputStream();
         dos.write(input.getBytes());
         dos.flush(); dos.close();
         // Retrieve the response back from the servlet
         dis = new DataInputStream(hc.openInputStream());
         int ch;
         // Check the Content-Length first
         long len = hc.getLength();
         if(len!=-1) {
         for(int i = 0;i<len;i++)

         if((ch = dis.read())!= -1)
         messagebuffer.append((char)ch);
         } else { // if the content-length is not available
         while ((ch = dis.read()) != -1)
         messagebuffer.append((char) ch);
         }
         dis.close();
         }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

Kindly suggest if I need to make any changes in the code.

Thanks in advance.

CB

Answer (score 1):

The MDS server will not allow a connection to 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

Comment: I have also tested with a server which is deployed at a different IP(machine) , kept at public domain.  How should I proceed with I need to test client server communcation using simulator ?

Comment: Ensure that the MDS simulator is starting. You can then use either the IP address or host name (that your DNS server will look up) for the network interface card on the machine with the server. This can be the same machine the simulators are running on, or a different machine. You can not use 127.0.0.1 or localhost.